# WebClient Not Handling KeepAlive - Adding unwanted text to JSON body

Tags: .net, json, webclient

I have a really strange issue that I can't seem to track down. I am posting small JSON objects to a webservice and getting back large JSON objects represented as strings. The problem I'm having is that randomly in the JSON object that is returned I get the following text:

> DNT: 1 Connection:      close

This obviously throws up when I try to deserialize the JSON. At first it was the Expect100-Continue in the body of the message, then it was the KeepAlive stuff and now it's the Connection: Close stuff. I am just using standard WebClient however I created a new class that inherits from WebClient so I can set the headers properly, here it is:

```
public class CustomWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request is HttpWebRequest)
        {
            (request as HttpWebRequest).KeepAlive = false;
            (request as HttpWebRequest).ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

and here is my implementation for the call:

```
using (var webClient = new CustomWebClient())
{
    webClient.Proxy = null;
    webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = Constants.HttpJSONencodedHeader;

    return webClient.UploadData(request.Url, Constants.HttpPostVerb, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request.Params.GetFormattedJSon()));
}
```

What I am expecting back is a JSON object that looks like this:

(simplified)

```
"276425": {
   "min": 1.0,
   "max": 1.0,
   "count": 1,
   "missing": 0,
   "distinctValues": [1],
   "countDistinct": 1,
   "sum": 1.0,
   "sumOfSquares": 1.0,
   "mean": 1.0,
   "stddev": 0.0,
   "facets": {}
}
```

This is what randomly comes back every now and then:

```
"280950": {
   "min": 1.0,
   "max": 1.0,
   "count": 1,
   "missing": 0,
   "distinctValues": [1],
   "countDistinct": 1,
   "sum": 1.
   DNT: 1
   Connection: close "stddev": 0.0,
   "facets": {}
}
```

the part to highlight is i have this right in the middle of the json object:

```
 .
        DNT: 1
        Connection: close
```

Any and all help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** The response is ~8 MB of text so i don't want to post the full response but here are the headers:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Set-Cookie: ServerID=1139; path=/
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/3.971 Win32NT/.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Tue, 31 Mar 2015 15:42:41 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 5802075
```

**Edit #2:**
Network Layout:

```
Client - ASP.NET 4.0 (IIS 7, Server 2012)
  Web Service - ASP.NET 4.0 ServiceStack v3.9.71.0
     SOLR 5 - Jetty (Linux, iunno some flavour)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the traffic in something like Wireshark? It sounds like it may be a bug in the web server being used...

Comment: Hey Jon - So it's actually a webservice (A) calling another webservice (B) that calls SOLR. I have captured the traffic in fiddler between B & A and see the content in there.

Comment: Right, so you should check what the responses look like - ideally include them in the question. It seems *unlikely* that WebClient would start putting response headers in the body...

Comment: Hey Jon - The response is 8 MB of JSON so i didn't want to post the entire body. The response headers all look fine and the body is just a ton of JSON with that DNT:1 Connection: close somewhere in the body. It doesn't always happen and never happens with small response (<2MB). I agree it seems VERY unlikely that the WebClient is adding this garbage but i dont know whatelse could possibly be adding it.

Comment: Well if the "Connection: close" is in the body (rather than in the headers) then it's the server's fault... how could the client (which makes a request) be adding text to the response?

Comment: Hey Jon - Correct me if i'm wrong but with long running connections doesn't the server respond with either the KeepAlive headers or something similar to let the client know its still processing? Isn't that what this 'DNT:1 Connection: close' actually is? It seems like the client is writing the KeepAlive headers to the body of the response instead of throwing them out.

Comment: I'd expect large responses to be chunked, potentially - but the server shouldn't be including the headers in the middle of the body. Note that in your edit, you've shown `Connection: close` in the headers of the response, not in the body...

Comment: Hey Jon - You are correct that the 'Connection: close' is in the header but it also in the body of the response which is where the problem is. Isn't the header the first thing sent down the stream to the client and then KeepAlive and what not just come down the stream to the client where that should be checked and thrown out?

Comment: Keep-Alive *is* a header - so it should be part of the headers in the request or response, not part of the body. All of this is a bit confused at the moment, but it does sound like the server you're talking to is at fault...

Comment: Hey Jon - The server is IIS 7 on Server 2012 and its a ServiceStack webservice. It seems just as unlikely that the server is the one causing the issues. I'll edit my original response and put more of a network diagram in there to give more details but it's lunch time and im hungry so ill do it when i get back. Thank you for your help, it might not sound like it but i do appreciate it.

Comment: Hey Jon - Sorry for the delay, stupid meetings, but i have added an edit to kinda show the flow of the response.